# Is it possible to define an ISM/ILM policy such that an action is only performed when all the conditions are met?

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

For instance, I want to rollover my index only when both `index_age:"1h"` AND `doc_count:1`

```
{
"policy": {
    "description": "Example rollover policy.",
    "default_state": "rollover",
    "states": [
        {
            "name": "rollover",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "rollover": {
                        "min_index_age": "1h",
                        "min_doc_count": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "transitions": []
        }
    ],
    "ism_template": {
        "index_patterns": [
            "log*"
        ],
        "priority": 100
    }
}
```

Doing at GET `/_opendistro/_ism/explain/log-000001?pretty` gave (excluded few fields):

```
{
"info": {
  "message": "Successfully rolled over index [index=log-000001]",
  "conditions": {
    "min_index_age": {
      "condition": "1h",
      "current": "1.1h",
      "creationDate": 1685093175627
    },
    "min_doc_count": {
      "condition": 1,
      "current": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Even though the 2nd condition was not met, still the rollover happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OPENSEARCH

Currently, there are only `min` conditions, and whenever one of the conditions is satisfied it will trigger the rollover.

[Rollover Official documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/im-plugin/ism/policies/#rollover)

> Rolls an alias over to a new index when the managed index meets **one of
> the rollover** conditions.

### ELASTICSEARCH

[Rollover official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-rollover-index.html)

There are `max` and `min` conditions available for Elasticsearch. You can use multiple **max** and **min** conditions.

> The index will rollover if **any max_*** condition is satisfied
> and **all min_*** conditions are satisfied.

An example:

The following request only rolls over the index if the current write index meets one or more of the following conditions:

- The index was created 7 or more days ago.
- The index contains 1,000 or more documents.
- The index’s largest primary shard is 50GB or larger.

---

```
POST my-data-stream/_rollover
{
  "conditions": {
    "max_age": "7d",
    "max_docs": 1000,
    "max_primary_shard_size": "50gb",
    "max_primary_shard_docs": "2000"
  }
}
```

***NOTE: max conditions released on Elasticsearch version [8.4](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/release-highlights.html#minimum_conditions_for_rollover_api_ilm_actions) and [7.17.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/release-notes-7.17.6.html), it's available for the versions I mentioned and above.***

Comment: I believe you have a typo in this answer.  You wrote:
**You can use multiple max conditions, which must be satisfied before rollover.**

But then you quoted something that says the opposite:
**The index will rollover if _any_ `max_` condition is satisfied and _all_ `min_` conditions are satisfied.**

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Mageician, you're right it can cause misunderstanding. I edited my answer.